# Red X in NetBeans Property Sheet

Tags: netbeans, javabeans

I've created a JavaBean with a custom editor and custom editor user interface for one of the properties.  The value field in the property sheet for this property displays a red x- how can this be removed?  And, what caused it to be there?

Answer (score 0):

Check var/log/messages under your [userdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir). Most likely there is an exception being raised when NB tries to instantiate your editor.